# How to export/ import ESM/ ES6 Module Properly in ESM aware Chrome

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, babel-loader

I have an app that I'm bundling with Webpack 4 and Babel loader.
In the main entry point I'm exporting a class, for example `export default Test;` Now I'm trying to import the main bundle in an ESM aware Chrome via

```
<script type="module">
(async function() {
  const test = await import('./module.main.js');
  window.test = test;
})()
</script>
```

The problem is that although the browser is loading the bundle, `test` only yields this.

```
Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

How can I get hold of my default export?
I'm not providing the Webpack config here because it's straight forward.

Comment: `test.default` should do.

Comment: For anyone having the same result (not containing default in the Module{} and wanting to access the exports, any solution to this?